# RCTBatchedBridge is deprecated and will be removed in a future React Native release

Tags: ios, react-native

I am facing this warning in my react Native App, How to solve this any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with my **existing native app**. I followed the [Integrating with Existing Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) guide and solved it.

Simply change `Podfile`

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    ...
    'BatchedBridge'
  ]
end
```

to

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    ...
    'CxxBridge'
  ]

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'GLog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
end
```

Comment: `glog` should be in lower case, see http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Comment: @Felix `GLog` works fine for me. I tried `glog` a few days ago, it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the ideal way is to refactor the module that uses RCTBatchedBridge to avoid the warning, but if this is out of your control you can hide the it with `console.ignoredYellowBox`:

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ["RCTBatchedBridge is deprecated and will be removed in a future React Native release."];
```

You can read more about it at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#warnings

Comment: Thanks @designorant I appreciate your suggestion but I am looking for specific alternative or you can say solution for this, We can hide warning but this is not my concern now.