# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/BatchedBridge"

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

I'm trying to run a `pod install` in an `ios` subdirectory of a React Native app. However, I'm running into the following error:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:ios kurtpeek$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `CodePush` from `../node_modules/react-native-code-push`
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
Fetching podspec for `SentryReactNative` from `../node_modules/react-native-sentry`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/BatchedBridge":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    React/BatchedBridge

  In Podfile:
    React/BatchedBridge (from `../node_modules/react-native`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `React/BatchedBridge (from `../node_modules/react-native`), React/BatchedBridge`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `LucyApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Here is the `Podfile`:

```
target 'LucyApp' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'BatchedBridge',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'Intercom'
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'






  pod 'SentryReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sentry'

end
```

Do I have to perhaps add a `pod 'BatchedBridge'` explicitly?

**Update**

In answer to [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme)'s queries about system, here are the contents of `React.podspec` in `../node_modules/react-native`:

```
# coding: utf-8
require "json"

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, "package.json")))
version = package['version']

source = { :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git' }
if version == '1000.0.0'
  # This is an unpublished version, use the latest commit hash of the react-native repo, which we’re presumably in.
  source[:commit] = `git rev-parse HEAD`.strip
else
  source[:tag] = "v#{version}"
end

folly_compiler_flags = '-DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1'

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name                    = "React"
  s.version                 = version
  s.summary                 = package["description"]
  s.description             = <<-DESC
                                React Native apps are built using the React JS
                                framework, and render directly to native UIKit
                                elements using a fully asynchronous architecture.
                                There is no browser and no HTML. We have picked what
                                we think is the best set of features from these and
                                other technologies to build what we hope to become
                                the best product development framework available,
                                with an emphasis on iteration speed, developer
                                delight, continuity of technology, and absolutely
                                beautiful and fast products with no compromises in
                                quality or capability.
                             DESC
  s.homepage                = "http://facebook.github.io/react-native/"
  s.license                 = package["license"]
  s.author                  = "Facebook"
  s.source                  = source
  s.default_subspec         = "Core"
  s.requires_arc            = true
  s.platforms               = { :ios => "8.0", :tvos => "9.2" }
  s.pod_target_xcconfig     = { "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++14" }
  s.preserve_paths          = "package.json", "LICENSE", "LICENSE-docs", "PATENTS"
  s.cocoapods_version       = ">= 1.2.0"

  s.subspec "Core" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "yoga", "#{package["version"]}.React"
    ss.source_files         = "React/**/*.{c,h,m,mm,S,cpp}"
    ss.exclude_files        = "**/__tests__/*",
                              "IntegrationTests/*",
                              "React/DevSupport/*",
                              "React/Inspector/*",
                              "ReactCommon/yoga/*",
                              "React/Cxx*/*",
    ss.ios.exclude_files    = "React/**/RCTTV*.*"
    ss.tvos.exclude_files   = "React/Modules/RCTClipboard*",
                              "React/Views/RCTDatePicker*",
                              "React/Views/RCTPicker*",
                              "React/Views/RCTRefreshControl*",
                              "React/Views/RCTSlider*",
                              "React/Views/RCTSwitch*",
                              "React/Views/RCTWebView*"
    ss.header_dir           = "React"
    ss.framework            = "JavaScriptCore"
    ss.libraries            = "stdc++"
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig  = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon\"" }
  end

  s.subspec "CxxBridge" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "Folly", "2016.09.26.00"
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.dependency             "React/cxxreact"
    ss.compiler_flags       = folly_compiler_flags
    ss.private_header_files = "React/Cxx*/*.h"
    ss.source_files         = "React/Cxx*/*.{h,m,mm}"
  end

  s.subspec "DevSupport" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.dependency             "React/RCTWebSocket"
    ss.source_files         = "React/DevSupport/*",
                              "React/Inspector/*"
  end

  s.subspec "tvOS" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "React/**/RCTTV*.{h, m}"
  end

  s.subspec "jschelpers" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "Folly", "2016.09.26.00"
    ss.dependency             "React/PrivateDatabase"
    ss.compiler_flags       = folly_compiler_flags
    ss.source_files         = "ReactCommon/jschelpers/*.{cpp,h}"
    ss.private_header_files = "ReactCommon/jschelpers/*.h"
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig  = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon\"" }
    ss.framework            = "JavaScriptCore"
  end

  s.subspec "jsinspector" do |ss|
    ss.source_files         = "ReactCommon/jsinspector/*.{cpp,h}"
    ss.private_header_files = "ReactCommon/jsinspector/*.h"
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig  = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon\"" }
  end

  s.subspec "PrivateDatabase" do |ss|
    ss.source_files         = "ReactCommon/privatedata/*.{cpp,h}"
    ss.private_header_files = "ReactCommon/privatedata/*.h"
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig  = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon\"" }
  end

  s.subspec "cxxreact" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/jschelpers"
    ss.dependency             "React/jsinspector"
    ss.dependency             "boost-for-react-native", "1.63.0"
    ss.dependency             "Folly", "2016.09.26.00"
    ss.compiler_flags       = folly_compiler_flags
    ss.source_files         = "ReactCommon/cxxreact/*.{cpp,h}"
    ss.exclude_files        = "ReactCommon/cxxreact/SampleCxxModule.*"
    ss.private_header_files = "ReactCommon/cxxreact/*.h"
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig  = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/ReactCommon\" \"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost-for-react-native\" \"$(PODS_ROOT)/DoubleConversion\" \"$(PODS_ROOT)/Folly\"" }
  end

  s.subspec "ART" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/ART/**/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTActionSheet" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTAnimation" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/NativeAnimation/{Drivers/*,Nodes/*,*}.{h,m}"
    ss.header_dir           = "RCTAnimation"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTBlob" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Blob/*.{h,m,mm}"
    ss.preserve_paths       = "Libraries/Blob/*.js"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTCameraRoll" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.dependency             'React/RCTImage'
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/CameraRoll/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTGeolocation" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Geolocation/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTImage" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.dependency             "React/RCTNetwork"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Image/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTNetwork" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Network/*.{h,m,mm}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTPushNotification" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTSettings" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Settings/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTText" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Text/**/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTVibration" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/Vibration/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTWebSocket" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.dependency             "React/RCTBlob"
    ss.dependency             "React/fishhook"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/WebSocket/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "fishhook" do |ss|
    ss.header_dir           = "fishhook"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/fishhook/*.{h,c}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTLinkingIOS" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/LinkingIOS/*.{h,m}"
  end

  s.subspec "RCTTest" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.source_files         = "Libraries/RCTTest/**/*.{h,m}"
    ss.frameworks           = "XCTest"
  end

  s.subspec "_ignore_me_subspec_for_linting_" do |ss|
    ss.dependency             "React/Core"
    ss.dependency             "React/CxxBridge"
  end
end
```

There is indeed no subspec `"BatchedBridge"`. As far as I can tell, there is also no reference to `BatchedBridge` in my local `~/node_modules`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:node_modules kurtpeek$ ls
balanced-match      fs.realpath     jasmine         path-is-absolute
brace-expansion     glob            jasmine-core        wrappy
concat-map      inflight        minimatch
exit            inherits        once
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:node_modules kurtpeek$ find . -name '*BatchedBridge*'
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:node_modules kurtpeek$ pwd
/Users/kurtpeek/node_modules
```

Comment: What's the podspec at path `'../node_modules/react-native'`? Could you share it? There: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React.podspec there is no `s.subspec "BatchedBridge" do |ss|`. Does your local version have one?

Comment: It has been deleted: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/816d41718998868f276d83b0c21e17d11ad392a2#diff-66230b3e029caa37b0fbdc8cbd47f4ab So either change the version to a one supporting it, or remove it. It's part of 0.54 Release, see the releases notes: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.54.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Releases Notes of 0.54.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.54.0), it has been removed:

> **iOS specific removals**
>
> Delete RCTBatchedBridge ([816d417](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/816d417) by [@mhorowitz](https://github.com/mhorowitz))

The commit [responsible](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/816d41718998868f276d83b0c21e17d11ad392a2#diff-66230b3e029caa37b0fbdc8cbd47f4ab) with the diff.

The commit message:

> Delete RCTBatchedBridge Summary:
>
> I've talked to several major
> community users, and they're all ok with deleting this code.  There's
> several doc fixes which will make it easier for third party developers
> which should land about the same time this will.
>
> Also buried along with it is RCTJSCExecutor.
>
> Reviewed By: javache
>
> Differential Revision: D6880781
>
> fbshipit-source-id: b4cb1143def6fd23a96290e478fa728adbedacd3

So you can either go back to as previous version (0.53.?) which still has it or get rid of it and remove it from your current code (and your *Podfile*).

Comment: As a follow-up question, how would I go back to the previous version? My `package.json` currently contains `"dependencies": {"react-native": "^0.53.3"}`; should I change that into a `0.53.3` (without the caret) and then run [`react-native-clean-project`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project)?

Comment: I don't use React. But https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#3-run-the-command ?

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47648111/75947 to update you podfile to remove RCTBatchedBridge

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should run the `pod repo update` it cannot find the latest version because your local cache is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently updated to React Native 0.63.2, a simple `pod update` should fix it.